# I need some help in relation to caps in GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I have the following pipeline:

```
pipeline_str = 
            g_strdup_printf ("rtspsrc name=source location=%s ! \
                decodebin ! video/x-raw ! videoconvert ! \
                textoverlay line-alignment=0 name=overlay font-desc=20 ! \
                videoscale ! video/x-raw, width=%d, height=%d ! videorate ! \
                x264enc name=encoder bitrate=%d key-int-max=4 ! \
                video/x-h264 ! \
                h264parse config-interval=1 ! \
                video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream, alignment=au ! \
                rtph264pay pt=96 ! udpsink host=%s port=%d", 
                _uri.c_str(), _width, _height, _bitrate, _address.c_str(), _port);
```

If I need to change the bitrate in the encoder I can do this:

```
GstElement *_encoder;
_encoder = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(data.pipeline), "encoder");
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(_encoder), "bitrate", _bitrate, NULL);
```

However, if i need to change the width or the height on run-time, I cant insert the name in the capfilter: "video/x-raw name=resol, width=%d, height=%d"

ERROR: could not parse caps "video/x-raw name=resol, width=1920, height=1080"

Being in this way, which would be the equivalent of "gst_bin_get_by_name" for caps and how could I name the caps, when I create the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Use the `capsfilter` itself. The syntax you are using is for convenience as it quite often being used.

Check the example here:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/coreelements/capsfilter.html?gi-language=c

On the first example you should also be able to set a name.

Comment: Great answer!! Thank you very much!